# How to print not match string

Tags: java

I would like to print not matching string but the result null.

```
public class Replacement  {
   public static void main(String[] ignored)  {

      String str = "aaa bbb ddd";
      Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<>();
      mapping.put("aaa", "hello");
      mapping.put("bbb", "java");
      mapping.put("ccc", "world");

      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z_]+)"); // pattern compiling
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str); // pattern matching

      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      while(matcher.find())  { // while matcher found
         String replace = mapping.get(matcher.group());
         matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replace + " ");
      }
      matcher.appendTail(sb);

      System.out.println(sb);
  }
}
```

The result:

> hello java null // I expected "hello java dddd

Do I need to put `while(!matcher.find())`

Comment: Since you don't have the key `dddd` on your map, it's correct to return **null**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to check whether a replacement exists or not, if replacement does not exist then you need to append the key itself

```
     String replace = mapping.get(matcher.group());
     if(replace==null) {
         replace = matcher.group();
     }
     matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replace + " ");
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The following code has been tested on IntelliJ 11 and appears to be working correctly.  I think your intention is to match each string in the `str` input, and potentially replace it, if it has a mapping in the hash map.  The problem is that you are doing a replace without actually checking if a matched word appears in the map.  I added logic that conditionally makes a replacement iff a match has a mapping.

```
public class Replacement  {
    public static void main(String[] ignored)  {

        String str = "aaa bbb ddd";
        Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapping.put("aaa", "hello");
        mapping.put("bbb", "java");
        mapping.put("ccc", "world");

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z_]+)");compiling
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(matcher.find())  {
            String key = matcher.group();       // matched word is key into the map
            String value = mapping.get(key);    // attempt to get mapped word
            if (value != null) {                // if mapping exists,
                str = str.replace(key, value);  //   then make replacement
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you need to worry about edge cases along the lines of what @ajb pointed out, it would be safer to just split your original string by space, selectively replace each word, and then roll it back up into a single string again:

```
String[] parts = str.split(" ");
String output = "";

for (int i=0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    String value = mapping.get(parts[i]);
    if (value == null) {
        value = parts[i];
    }

    if (i > 0) {
        output += " ";
    }
    output += value;
}
```

Comment: I don't think your new version does the same thing as the OP's intent.  Suppose the input is `"abbba bbb"`.  `abbba` doesn't match anything in the map, so I think it's supposed to be left in the string as is, but your `str.replace()` defeats that.

Comment: @ajb, No, that is not correct.  My code _leaves_ anything in the string which does not map.  You didn't read the code carefully nor did you run it.

Comment: I just ran it, replacing the initial value of `str` with `"abbba bbb"`, and removing the extraneous "compiling" from the line that defines `pattern`.  The result: `"ajavaa java"`.  Running the OP's code (adding a check for `replace != null`) results in `"abbba java"`.  So yes, I did read the code carefully.  And I think the latter is what the OP is looking for, although my mind-reading skills are suspect.

Comment: @ajb If such edge cases can happen, then I don't think using a matcher is the best way to go here.  Ultimately, the decision to replace is determined by whether a substring appears in a hashmap.  This logic should determine the approach taken, and splitting the string seems like a sound approach.

Comment: I don't think that a word being a substring of another word is an "edge case"--it occurs all the time in English.  Say that instead of `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, he was trying to replace `rat` with `mouse`, `cat` with `lion`, etc, and the word `bratwurst` was in the input.  I like using `split` here, but the OP's original approach would have worked fine also, except for the bug.

Comment: @ajb This may be a homework assignment, and if not required, then yes this would be an edge case here.  I agree with your point, and I think splitting the string and doing a lookup on each word is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no match in the map, `mapping.get()` would return `null` in this code:

```
     String replace = mapping.get(matcher.group());
     matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replace + " ");
```

I'm not sure what you expected.  It seems like you thought that if the string wasn't in the map, the code would magically know that you would want to skip the `appendReplacement`.  But, of course, code can't read minds and doesn't work magically.  If `replace` is `null`, the program would still go ahead and try to execute the next line.

The result you're seeing is because of how the `+` operator works on strings; if one of the operands is `null`, then `+` actually puts the four-character string `"null"` into the result.  Thus, `replace + " "` is `"null "`, and the code replaces your unmatched string with that.  (However, this:

```
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replace);
```

would have given you a NullPointerException.)

So basically, you want to tell it not to do the replacement if there's no match, and there are a couple ways to do this:

```
 String replace = mapping.get(matcher.group());
 if (replace != null) {
     matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replace + " ");
 }
```

or

```
if (mapping.containsKey(matcher.group())) {
    String replace = mapping.get(matcher.group());
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replace + " ");
}
```

Because of the way `appendReplacement` works, if you skip it for one `matcher.find()`, it doesn't touch `matcher`'s *append position*.  So the next time through the loop, if there is a match, the previous match (that didn't have a mapping) would get copied in at that point.  Or, if we fall out of the loop, the previous match would get copied by `appendTail`.

But note that the code you wrote is inserting *extra* spaces into the result.  If that's what you want, then you might want to fix the replacement so that it adds an extra space even if there's no mapping, instead of just copying it in the next `append`.

```
 String replace = mapping.get(matcher.group());
 if (replace == null) {
     replace = matcher.group();
 }
 matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replace + " ");
```

which would in effect replace `"ddd"` by `"ddd "` in your example.  You'll have to decide how you want to handle the spaces.  Maybe you really didn't want extra spaces?  Remember that the `append` methods will copy text from the input up to the point that matched, including those space characters.  So you really don't need to include an extra space, unless you really want to increase the number of spaces in the result.

Comment: You can see by virtue of which answer was accepted that the OP wanted a simple fix, not necessarily one which can conquer the world.  I look forward to interacting with you again on SO.